# Is there "Show potential fixes(ctrl+.)" support for F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

What I said is like this in `C#`
[image]

It's very annoying when I need to manually add all `open` for the type I use in `F#` source code.Especially When I am not very familiar with the reference I work with.

If I forget the namespace,I open the object browser ,type the class name I am using, wait 1 or 2 second let VS finish freezing and get the namespace I want.

All I want is something like `open namespace tip`.I have searched it for more than half hour and I can not even find anyone asked the similar question.

Or It's all my fault and I should remember all the namespace the type I am using when I am coding???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Visual F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff), which can be installed on Visual Studio via *Extensions and Updates*.

List of current features:

- Auto-generating XmlDoc
- Formatting document / Formatting selection
- Navigation bar
- Highlight references
- Rename refactoring
- Depth colorizer
- NavigateTo
- Syntax coloring
- Folder organization
- Find all references
- Implement interface
- Record stub generation
- Union pattern match case generation
- Resolve unopened namespaces
- Gray out unused declarations
- Gray out unused open declarations
- Go to metadata
- Task List comments
- Generate references for F# Interactive
- Navigate to source
- Quick info panel
- FsLinter integration

More details in the link above, and on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools).

Comment: I forget it.... ....The reason I can't find any related ask is everyone coding F# using Power Tools....Thank you very much... ....